# Getting Imagine Bundle service synchronously with an Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need [Avalanche Imagine Bundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) to give me my Image entity's thumbnail location each time I load it from database.

As it says on their github page, doing this is quite simple in controller:

```
$avalancheService = $this->get('imagine.cache.path.resolver');
$cachedImage = $avalancheService->getBrowserPath($object->getWebPath(), 'my_thumb');
```

The problem is, I don't want this in my controller. I need my entity to call this every time I load it from database, but I can't access Symfony services from inside my entity. As I found, I really shouldn't be able to get service container as "Entities should only know about themselves and other entities", but how do I achieve what I want?

Specifically, how do I call service method and store it's value inside an entity property on each entity load?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an entity manager that manages creation, loading, updating etc. of a certain entity type.

For example with FOSUserBundle you may want to use the [UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md) in order to create a user entity instead of doing it the old way.

```
// Good
$user = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->createUser();

// Not so good
$user = new User();
```

This way you can delegate management to another class (in this case [UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php)) and add extra controls.

So let's say you have an entity `Foo`. You will have to create a service `FooManager` that automatically ties `Imagine` to `Foo` at creation and loading.

Entity :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

class Foo
{
    protected $id;

    protected $imagine;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setImagine($imagine)
    {
        $this->imagine = $imagine;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImagine()
    {
        return $this->imagine;
    }

    public function getBrowserPath()
    {
        return $this->imagine->getBrowserPath($this->getWebPath(), 'my_thumb')
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return 'the_path';
    }
}
```

Manager :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Manager;

class FooManager
{
    // Service 'imagine.cache.path.resolver' injected by DIC
    protected $imagine;

    // Entity repository injected by DIC
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct($imagine, $repository)
    {
        $this->imagine = $imagine;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        // Load entity from database
        $foo = $this->repository->find($id);

        // Set the Imagine service so we can use it inside entities
        $foo->setImagine($this->imagine);

        return $foo;
    }
}
```

Then you will use something like `$foo = $container->get('foo_manager')->find($id);`.

Of course you will have to tweak this classes a bit.

Not sure if it's the best way to do this but it's the only workaround I've found as we can't inject services into entities.

Comment: Thanks for your response! After trying this, I found a solution that works but specifically for my case. I only needed to get thumbLocations "manually" (outside of view) while rendering forms (I needed to render image thumbnail next to each checkbox/radiobutton). I ended up making my custom FormType service and injecting dependencies into it. Then it would simply get thumbnail locations for each entity. Essentially, I made my FormType serve as FooManager. It isn't very elegant solution as I really don't think FormType should do this kind of stuff but works.